# Functional component emit event: Expression is not callable - Vue

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

Functional component with render function:

```
render(createElement, { listeners } {
  return createElement('div', {
    on: {
      click: () => {
        // issue is on this line
        const onItemClick: any = listeners['item-click']
        onItemClick(1, 2, 3)
      }
    }
  })
}
```

How to correctly type `onItemClick` so i won't get an error:

```
const onItemClick: Function | Function[]
This expression is not callable.
  No constituent of type 'Function | Function[]' is callable.ts(2349)
```

Signature of `listeners`:

```
var listeners: {
    [key: string]: Function | Function[];
}
```

Comment: It says array is not callable, check if array -> call each else call value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it using type assertion:

```
const onItemClick = listeners['item-click'] as (val1: string, val2: string) => void
onItemClick('123, '456')
```

Comment: Type assertion is not a true solution and seems like a workaround. I wonder why the type is `Function | Function[]`.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the arrow function with the `function()` constructor.

```
on: { click: function() { // do the stuff }}
```